# How to add RecyclerView in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

I need to add a RecyclerView in ScrollView.
The RecyclerView should wrap its contents and shouldn't be be scrollable, but the entire scroll view should be scrollable. 
Can this be done an how?

Comment: `RecyclerView should wrap its contents and shouldn't be be scrollable` What is the point?

Comment: Put the `RecyclerView` on top, put the `ScrollView` on bottom. Don't nest.

Comment: point is that only the ScrollView is scrollable, @RofueBaneling i need the entire screen to be scrollable and not only half of the screen

Comment: @user1796624 Scroll views are scrollable naturally. Do not mix two scrollable views together unless they are going in opposite directions. (Eg. recyclerview is horizontal and scrollview is vertical)

Comment: @user1796624 what a point of having `RecyclerView` whose main purpose is performance optimization in cases when there are too many views. If your `RecyclerView` is so small that there are not enough views, then you don't need it at all.

Comment: [SOLVED] solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37619660/1303639

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Recycler view adpater class

you will be having getITemViewType function

from that you can manage to put you scrollview content in one type of item

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER1;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER2;
        } else {
            return VIEWTYEPITEM;
        }
    }


@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            final ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == VIEWTYEPITEM) {
            //return item view
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER2) {
            //return item view 2
        } else {
            //return item view 1

        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but i explicitly need to add the RecyclerView in the ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Main purpose of `RecyclerView` (as well as of old `ListView` and `GridView`) is performance optimization in cases when you have so many views in the list, that they do not fit on the screen and therefore are scrollable.

If your `RecyclerView` is so small that there are not enough views to fill it or there is some constant (and small) amount of views - then you don't need to use it at all. You won't win anything. Moreover, when you have one scrollable view inside of another scrollable view - how do you expect it to work? Which view should scroll when? It is ambiguous that's why it is not possible to do.

On the other hand, if you have a lot of views, then you better of using just `RecyclerView` without a `ScrollView`. In such situation it's common to add some sort of header or footer views which are arbitrarily big. Since `RecyclerView` is already scrollable, they will work as you want it to work. @SHASHIDHAR MANCHUKONDA exlained this idea in his answer to your question.

Comment: I have small number of elements(small list) in the view from 2-15 items but they number is  changing and i also have the option to change them so i need a RecyclerView or a ListView. It is about adding passengers and changing their details and so on. But this list according to design should be a part of a bigger scrollable view that has other details this other details cant be put in a list or be a part of the same list since they are from totally different nature and don't repeat. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user1796624 I see, it's quite common UI pattern. I would go with `RecyclerView` + headers/footers attached to it. In `ListView` it was possible to just call `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView`. In `RecyclerView` you have to do it yourself. @SHASHIDHAR MANCHUKONDA explained it more or less (or you can Google for better answer). In any case, `RecyclerView` + `ScrollView` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the scrolling of the ScrollView. Is is perfect upon 5.0.

```
public class UnScrollView extends ScrollView{
private int downX;
private int downY;
private int mTouchSlop;

public UnScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
}

public UnScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
}

public UnScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int action = e.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = (int) e.getRawX();
            downY = (int) e.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int moveY = (int) e.getRawY();
            if (Math.abs(moveY - downY) > mTouchSlop) {
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
}
```

}