# how to prevent loading of all item of recyclerview in scrollview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView and I want to scroll all of the items in my screen, and I get data from the server. my problem is each item of RecyclerView has a photo, and because of nesting scrolling, recycler assumes that the height of the page is unlimited so it gets all of the items from the server and tries to download all photos, and this makes scrolling not smooth!!
my question is, is there any way to download only shown items photo in RecyclerView? (I know RecyclerView itself does that! but it's not working inside a scrollView)

note :I've also seen similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879646/how-to-add-recyclerview-in-scrollview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425020/recyclerview-part-of-scrollview). the first one provides an acceptable solution but requires a lot of change for me! therefor I'm looking for a better solution!

Comment: Do this way . For that one of the idea is to use pagination concept @Azin.I only shows the visible items until you scroll for additional data so until you scroll the next photos are not shown right?

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta yes, it downloads all photos which are not showing.

Comment: Technically I don't think so because when the first time recyclerview loads it only loads the visible item then how come the other data downloads is my question. Correct me if I am wrong @Azin

Comment: generally what you saying should be correct, but because it is inside a Scrollview, recycler thinks it should load all items and all of them are visible ! so it downloads all images needed to be shown! you can try it yourself and see it download all items in recyclerview from the Server

Comment: Nice observation @Azin.Thank you.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta your welcome, in the end, I couldn't find any solution and I changed the whole adapter and placed the static part into my adapter and it solved my problem.

Comment: That's great.Nice to hear @Azin

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)? It only load photos when it is visible.

Comment: I use Picasso and it also loads photos when they are visible! I don't think it's about downloading photos!! it's about creating all cell of RecyclerView when it is in scrollView